# DDEV Drupal: How to restore backups with backup_migrate module when saved as GZip?

Tags: drupal, ddev

In connection with backup_migrate module.

I am seeing that when backups are saved with GZip compression to the private files directory, it is not possible to restore from them or download them. Attempting to do so results in a 404 error. However, backups saved in Zip format work without problems.

This appears to be an nginx thing as I do not see this with DrupalVM or Acquia Dev Desktop.

Is some extra configuration needed?

---

DDEV VERSION
domain  ddev.local
cli     v0.17.0
web     drud/nginx-php-fpm-local:v1.2.2
db      drud/mariadb-local:v0.9.0
dba     drud/phpmyadmin:v0.2.0
router  drud/ddev-router:v0.5.0
commit  v0.17.0

DOCKER VERSION
Docker version 17.12.1-ce, build 7390fc6

CONFIG.YML
APIVersion: "1"
name: easable-schools
type: drupal8
docroot: public_html/web
php_version: "7.1"
webimage: drud/nginx-php-fpm-local:v1.2.2
dbimage: drud/mariadb-local:v0.9.0
dbaimage: drud/phpmyadmin:v0.2.0
router_http_port: "8000"
router_https_port: "8443"
additional_hostnames: []
provider: default

Comment: I opened https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/847 about this. In the meantime, Is your private files on the repository mount (inside your project root?) If it is, it's already available to you in the host in that directory. If not, you can `ddev ssh` and move it into a place where it's available on the mounted project. Thanks for catching this!   Also note that `ddev import-db` doesn't quite work with .mysql files yet, but will soon, https://github.com/drud/ddev/pull/824. In the meantime, you can gunzip and change the extension mysql to .sql.

Comment: @rfay My private files directory is within the project root and one level above the docroot. Odd how everything is fine with zip compression but not gz

Comment: I did actually discover the nginx rule that's causing this, will be able to fix it.

Comment: https://github.com/drud/ddev/pull/858 should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/847 and is no longer an issue in current versions of ddev.